# Are these two Java and C# statements equal?

Tags: c#, java, .net, interface

in C#

```
class ListMap<K, E>
    : ImyMap<K, E>, IComparable<K>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, E>>
{
}
```

in Java

```
class MyListMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, E>
    implements MyMap<K,E>, Iterable<KeyValuePair<K, E>>
{
}
```

Just trying to convert some data structures from Java into C# and wanted to know if my C# implementation is equal to my Java one.

If not can you please correct it?

Comment: Better to ask it at code review

Comment: It is my own personal stuff and that type of comment makes a mockery of this entire site.

Comment: but thanks anyway for your constructive feedback.

Comment: It's not mockery as all these sites are managed by stack exchange for all types of topics.

Comment: I thought you meant code review at my school or company... Apologies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, those are not equal. The `K extends ...` portion needs to be translated into a constraint:

```
class ListMap<K, E>
    : ImyMap<K, E>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, E>>
   where K : IComparable<K>
{
}
```

The wildcard `? super K` is not necessary in C#. Wildcards are Java's way to support co/contravariance. In C#, this is done as part of the interface declaration:

```
interface IComparable<in K> { ... }
```

The `in` modifier makes the interface contravariant, which has the same effect as the wildcard in Java.

Comment: That's what I was going for, but was worried by this: do we need to tweak the `K : IComparable<K>` to allow for the fact we have `K extends Comparable<? super K>` rather than `K extends Comparable<K>` ?

Comment: Awesome, That is the portion I kept having trouble with in C#. Kind of new to it for the most part and trying to implement my own data structures in it.

Comment: I have never even seen that bit about the where before, I love the internet thank you guys!

Comment: @Rawling: I extended my answer to explain the wildcard.

Comment: Aah, variance covers it? I was wondering if you had to add a dummy type parameter and do `where K : IComparable<SuperK> where K : SuperK`